# How to trigger a compile-time error when using a bad default import in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am migrating an existing codebase to TypeScript. From [#5565](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5565), I know that I need to change my import statements for external modules from a default import (`import slug from 'slugg'`) to a namespace import (`import * as slug from 'slugg'`). The website is mostly working now, but there are places where I missed changing the import. This causes a run-time error when the module is actually used: `Uncaught TypeError: slugg_1.default is not a function`.

Is there a way to make this a compile-time error?

I have two `tsconfig.json` files. One is for the front end (used by `awesome-typescript-loader`/`webpack`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "jsx": "react",
        "lib": ["es2015", "es2016", "es2017", "dom"],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5"
    }
}
```

And one is for the back end (used by `ts-node`):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es2017"
    }
}
```

At first I thought it might be a problem specific to `webpack` or `ts-node`, but `webpack` builds without any errors, and the server starts without any errors. I'm new to TypeScript, so any insight would be appreciated. I did find [another issue](https://github.com/molnarg/js-schema/issues/49) that suggests this situation just isn't caught at compile-time.

Comment: There is a detailed explanations how export default works: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2242#issuecomment-83694181

Comment: Thanks. I did manage to get compile time errors once I installed the type definitions for the packages.

Comment: If it was helpful upvote :)